# How do I create a CacheFile object for a Mesh Sequence Cache modifier?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I’m very new to the blender API (so forgive the noob-ness) but have experience with python and the maya API.

I’m trying to write a simple batch script to attach alembic animation caches to a series of geometries using the mesh sequence cache modifier. It’s a simple for loop that needs to create the modifier then set the parameters.

```
import bpy 

anim_cache_file = 'C:/Users/example/Desktop/cache/example.abc'

for geo in bpy.data.collections["geo_collection"].objects:
    
    object_path = "/{0}/{0}Shape".format(geo.name)
    
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = geo
    modifier = geo.modifiers.new(name="cache", type='MESH_SEQUENCE_CACHE')
    modifier.cache_file = bpy.ops.cachefile.open(filepath=anim_cache_file)
    modifier.object_path = object_path
```

Currently, i’m working through the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshSequenceCacheModifier.html):

**I need to supply a CacheFile but I have been unable to initialize an instance.**

It’s mentioned [**here**](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html) (under heading Data Creation/Removal) that new data-blocks in the bpy API can’t be created by calling the class. Instead data is added and removed via methods on the collections. **The problem is I cannot find the relevant method to create a Cache file.**

If anyone is across this I’d really appreciate some guidance.

Cheers

Comment: Operators return a status set, eg `{'FINISHED}`